# How to debug gulp plugins during developing using Visual Studio 2015 / Community / Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, gulp

I need to debug a gulp plugins during development using Visual Studio 2015 / Community or Visual Studio Code.

By debugging I mean using the IDE features like break point and so on, not only printing in the console.

Comment: the only useful article I found so far: https://hansrwindhoff.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/debugging-task-runner-tasks-like-gulp-with-visual-studio-code-editordebugger/

Answer (score 0):

A find out a solution to this issue.
Basically it is possible to attach Visual Studio Code to Node.js process, so when running script in node, Visual Studio debugger come up.

Attaching VS Code to Node.js

```
node --debug program.js
```

or

`node --debug-brk program.j`s

Usingthe `--debug-brk` option, Node.js stops on the first line of the program.

The corresponding launch.json configuration in VS looks like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "restart": false
        }
    ]
}
```

More information can be found her:

http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations